# Array not working when more than one value is provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

This is my code for my `Page_Load`:

```
string _group_array = Group_Array.Get_Group_Array(3);

string[] groups = new string[] { _group_array };

foreach (string group in groups)
  {
     GridView grdv = new GridView();
     grdv.DataSource = Connections.isp_GET_GRIDVIEW_DATA("STDNG", group, "", "");
     grdv.DataBind();

     gridview_holder.Controls.Add(grdv);
  }
```

And this is the code for my `Group_Array` class:

```
public static String Get_Group_Array(int count)
{
    string _cs_group_array = "";

    if(count == 1)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A";
    }
    else if(count == 2)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A, B";
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A, B, C";
    }

    return _cs_group_array;
}
```

My issue is that when my count is greater than 1, my `groups` does not work. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Get_Group_Array only returns a single string not an array.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: Change second line to `string[] groups = _group_array.Split(",");`

Comment: No, I expect to get something like "A", "B", "C"

Comment: What you expecting to see in variable `group` from your `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem1 :** you are not seperating the group string `_group_array` using comma as delimiter .

**Solution1 :** you need to split the group string `_group_array` using comma as delimiter.

**Note:** you can use `Split()` function for Splitting the string.

Replace  This:

```
string[] groups = new string[] { _group_array };
```

With This:

```
string[] groups = _group_array.Split(',');
```

**Problem 2:** you have spaces between the strings.

**Solution 2:** you need to remove the spaces between the strings.

Replace This:

```
else if(count == 2)
{
    _cs_group_array = "A, B";
}
else if (count == 3)
{
    _cs_group_array = "A, B, C";
}
```

With This:

```
   else if(count == 2)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A,B";
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A,B,C";
    }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
string _group_array = Group_Array.Get_Group_Array(3);
string[] groups = _group_array.Split(',');

foreach (string group in groups)
  {
     GridView grdv = new GridView();
     grdv.DataSource = Connections.isp_GET_GRIDVIEW_DATA("STDNG", group, "", "");
     grdv.DataBind();

     gridview_holder.Controls.Add(grdv);
  }
public static String Get_Group_Array(int count)
{
    string _cs_group_array = "";

    if(count == 1)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A";
    }
    else if(count == 2)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A,B";
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A,B,C";
    }

    return _cs_group_array;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the space between the chars too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest what I think is a cleaner approach:

```
string[] groups = new [] { "A", "B", "C" }.Take(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Get_Group_Array` method always returns one string, not a string array.That's why your foreach is executing only once because your `groups` array has only one element. According to your code you can change your method like this:

```
public static string[] Get_Group_Array(int count)
{
   string _cs_group_array = "";

   if(count == 1)
   {
     _cs_group_array = "A";
    } 
    else if(count == 2)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A, B";
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        _cs_group_array = "A, B, C";
    }

     return _cs_group_array.Split(',');
}
```

Then call it:

```
string[] groups = Group_Array.Get_Group_Array(3);
```

If you want to make it better:

```
public static string[] Get_Group_Array(int count)
{
     string[] chars = new string[count];
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         chars[i] = ((char) i + 65).ToString();
     }

     return chars;
}
```